# Checking for norm-Euclidean with a computer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, computer-algebra

Let $K$ be a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $O$ the ring of integers in $K$.

> Question: Is there an algorithm to test whether $O$ is norm-euclidean?

In case the question has a positive answer:

For Pari it is said that assuming the generalised Riemann hypothesis makes checking for class number one up to 1000 time faster (see for example [Number fields](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field.html)).

Is a similar statement about the generalised Riemann hypothesis true for checking norm-Euclidean?

Comment: Jean-Paul Cerri, Pierre Lezowski